# null is not a valid include error message

Tags: java, liferay, portal

I have a liferay portlet class in which I write an init() method. After deploying it, when I place the portlet on the page it is empty and I get "null is not a valid include" error when I check the log file. But when I remove the init() method it works without problem. My init() method is as simple as this:

```
public void init() throws PortletException{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend your portlet using MVCPortlet. If you are already using MVCPortlet either don't include the init method or make sure you call super.init().

Comment: So where I should do intializations when using MVCPortlet?

Comment: you can use init() but make sure you call super.init() in your custom portlet class if you want to override the method